# Passing data from gridview

Tags: gridview, webforms

I've a grid view at `FriendsList.aspx`. Through this grid view, I will be able to see all the friends that I have. I can then navigate to `FriendsDetails.aspx` to view the details of a particular friend.

I can pass data from `FriendsList.aspx` to `FriendsDetails.aspx`.
However, I was unsure of how to use the passed value from `FriendList.aspx`.

Someone please enlighten me as to how can I go about doing this.

The code of my `ItemTemplate`. (I retrieve my data from a sql datasource)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink 
          ID="HyperLink1" 
          runat="server" 
          Text="View friend's profile"
          NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/FriendsList.aspx?FriendID={0}", Eval("FriendID")) %>'>
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The route you're taking looks fine. (Not sure about syntactical correctness however.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pull friendid from the request in the page.load handler and query the database

```
page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var friendid = Request["FriendID"];
    var friend = getfriendfromdatabase(friendid);
    //use friend to load the controls.
}
```

Comment: Let's say for a particular friend i have 3 pages.

Comment: the same method of passing friendID ?